# Joining two tables where one contains multiple rows that refer to one row in the other table PSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, pivot

So I have two tables that look like this:

`nalog`:

```
prod_num
id
```

`qa_stavka_kontrola`:

```
status
id_nalog
id
redak --question id
```

The second table is used to store yes or no answers (in column status(boolean)) about books that are contained in the first table. Multiple rows of the second table refer to one row in the first one. I want to make a report that looks something like this:

```
|prod_num | question 1 | question 2 | question 3 | 
|52       |     1      |     0      |     1      |
|53       |     0      |     1      |     1      |
```

This is my query but it is very very slow:

```
select nalog.prod_num
      , r1.status as question1
      , r2.status as question2
      , r3.status as question3
from nalog
     left join qa_stavka_kontrola as r1 
     on nalog.id=r1.id_nalog and r1.redak=1 and (r1.status=1 or r1.status=0)
     left join qa_stavka_kontrola as r2 
     on nalog.id=r2.id_nalog and r2.redak=2 and (r2.status=1 or r2.status=0)
     left join qa_stavka_kontrola as r3 
     on nalog.id=r3.id_nalog and r3.redak=3  and (r3.status=1 or3.status=0)
where nalog.date BETWEEN '2017-09-01' and '2018-01-11'
group by nalog.prod_num, r1.status, r2.status, r3.status
```

Comment: So it's a maximum of three questions? And there can not be multiple entries per id_nalog and redak in qa_stavka_kontrola?

Answer (score 0):

I might be off, but you can try to use PIVOT, check documentation for more info.

```
with something as
(select t1.prod_num, t2.redak 
from nalog t1
left outer join qa_stavka_kontrola t2
on t1.id=t2.id_nalog
where t2.status in (0,1)
and t1.date BETWEEN '2017-09-01' and '2018-01-11' -- is there a date column?
)
select *
from something
pivot (count(redak) for redak  in (1 as question_1, 2 as question_2, 3 as question_3));
```